# Using sidebarLayout with fillPage

Tags: r, layout, shiny

I tried to use `sidebarLayout` with `fillPage` in order to fit the plot to full window-size. Below is my attempt but it seems that not working. How could I correct my code to make it work?

Thank you in advance.

```
library(plotly)
if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fillPage(titlePanel("Active in last day"),
                 sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(
                     dateRangeInput(
                       "date_time_1",
                       "Time",
                       min = '2014-12-01',
                       max = Sys.Date() - 1,
                       start = Sys.Date() - 60,
                       end =  Sys.Date() - 1
                     ),
                     actionButton("btn_download", "Download"),
                     width = 3
                   ),

                   # Show a plot of the generated distribution
                   mainPanel(fillRow(
                     plotly::plotlyOutput(
                       outputId = "chart",
                       width = "100%",
                       height = "100%"
                     ),
                     height = "100%"
                   ))
                 ))

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$chart <- renderPlotly({
      Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
      SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
      LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
      data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)
      plot_ly(
        data,
        x = ~ Animals,
        y = ~ SF_Zoo,
        type = 'bar',
        name = 'SF Zoo'
      ) %>%
        add_trace(y = ~ LA_Zoo, name = 'LA Zoo') %>%
        layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'group')
    })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sidebarlayout is causing that problem. I have edited your code so that it occupies the entire page.

```
library(plotly)
if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fillPage(titlePanel("Active in last day"),
                 #sidebarLayout(
                   #sidebarPanel(
                     dateRangeInput(
                       "date_time_1",
                       "Time",
                       min = '2014-12-01',
                       max = Sys.Date() - 1,
                       start = Sys.Date() - 60,
                       end =  Sys.Date() - 1
                     ),
                     actionButton("btn_download", "Download"),
                     width = 3
                   #)
                 ,

                   # Show a plot of the generated distribution
                   #mainPanel(
                     fillRow(
                     plotly::plotlyOutput(
                       outputId = "chart",
                       width = "100%",
                       height = "100%"
                     ),
                     height = "100%"
                   )#)
                 )#)

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$chart <- renderPlotly({
      Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
      SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
      LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
      data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)
      plot_ly(
        data,
        x = ~ Animals,
        y = ~ SF_Zoo,
        type = 'bar',
        name = 'SF Zoo'
      ) %>%
        add_trace(y = ~ LA_Zoo, name = 'LA Zoo') %>%
        layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'group')
    })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I still play around to find a solution. Might be switch to flexdashboard to see if it works